# C++ base class pointers, collection classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class of Animal and derived class of Dog, Cat.

I also have a DogCollection, CatCollection class to manage operations such as adding a new cat etc, reading a cat, and removing a cat from the database, searching for a specific cat using a pointer to the Dog and Cat class.

I have been asked to use base class pointers to manage the classes in a single container. Is it better practice to perform the read of and write operations in the Dog and Cat classes instead of a separate DogCollection and CatCollection classes for this purpose?

Comment: Please show some code. Your final paragraph is a bit confusing to me. I understand this is homework. It sounds like you've been asked to use an `AnimalCollection` instead of a `DogCollection` and `CatCollection`, but I couldn't understand your final question.

Comment: My understanding you are asked to have a container of pointers to `Animal` where you store pointers to `Dog`s and `Cat`s. So, I suppose, you are talking about virtual dispatch.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is 
`Dog wMyDog;`

`Animal * wAnimal = wMyDog;`

Answer (score 2):

In common c++, you would typically use templated containers to hold objects, like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Cat;
class Dog;
class Animal;

typedef std::vector<Cat*> CatCollection;
typedef std::vector<Dog*> DogCollection;
typedef std::vector<Animal*> AnimalCollection;
```

I used [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as the container, but there are others available.

Then you would manipulate the container as a container and perform the operations  on the items themselves, like:

```
AnimalCollection coll;

//add elements
Cat *cat = ...;
Dog *dog = ...;

coll.push_back(cat);
coll.push_back(dog);

//do something with the first item of the collection
coll[0] -> doStuff();

//do something on all items
for (Animal *c: coll) {
    c -> doStuff();
}

//Don't forget to delete allocated objects one way or the other
//std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> can for example take ownership of pointers and delete them when the collection is destroyed
```

Creating a specific collection class for a specific type can be done in specialized cases but it's not usual.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/QpdR8a)

Comment: Well that depends on the fact that you might need to perform specific operation on the instance or some array manipulation that you would want to encapsulate in a distinct class.

Comment: @coyotte508 To which class does doStuff() belong to?

Comment: If it is `virtual` and overriden in children classes `Cat` and `Dog`, then the one for `Cat` or `Dog` will be called. I'll edit with a live example soon.